# Where can I find Samsung SP1203N 120gb internal hard drive firmware update?

Tags: hard-drive, download, firmware

I am trying to update the firmware for this drive. I ran a program which messed up the SMART readings on the drive and want to get a newer version of the firmware to fix the issue. My current firmware version is TL100-23. If you have yourself or can point me to a site that has a newer version available for download please reply with a link.

Also, if you think it's impossible to find this for free, I'd like to know: why is it so hard to find?

Frankly, I was very suprised that I couldn't find it by searching the web.

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact Samsung directly for firmware updates, I do not find any firmware updates for that model on the Samsung website, but it is old (2003), they may have it archived and may send you a link to it if it exists.

The only ones Samsung has publicly available:
3.5 inch HDD (SP2014N / SP2514N / SP2004C / SP2504C / HD040HJ / HD080HJ / HD120IJ 
/HD160JJ / SP1253N / SP1654N)

https://contactus.samsung.com/customer/contactus/formmail/mail/MailQuestionGeneral.jsp?SITE_ID=76&PROD_ID=1274

Using firmware updates from other sources could brick the drive.

.